# What does other sects & acharyas believe in Bhagavad Gita 7.19 Sloka except Vasinava Acharayas or Sects?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, krishna, philosophy, bhagavad-gita

Most of every acharyas accepted Bhagavad Gita is best medium to attain Moksha and gave their commentary on it. And Bhagavad Gita is also accepted as authenticate holy book in Most of every Vedanta Schools.

So, Here my Question on this Sloka of Shrimad Bhagavad Gita:

> **बहूनां जन्मनामन्ते ज्ञानवान्मां प्रपद्यते।**
>
> **वासुदेवः सर्वमिति स महात्मा सुदुर्लभः।।7.19।।**

Meaning

> > "After many births and deaths, he who is actually in knowledge surrenders unto Me, knowing Me Vasudev: to be the cause of all causes and all that is. Such a great soul is very rare."

What does other acharyas and sects talked or interpreted on this particular sloka of **Bhagavad Gita**, where lord himself declared as Shree Narayana (Shree Krsna) as causes of everything.

Answer (score 8):

"I" or "Me" in Bhagavad Gita is interpreted differently by different philosophers. But in [Anugita Parva of Aswamedha Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14016.htm) of Mahabharata clearly says Lord Krishna was in union with Supreme Brahman at time of Bhagavad Gita recitation. Different schools interpret that "Supreme Brahman" differently.

So, not only Vaishnava acharyas, even Advaitins believe in entire Bhagavad Gita. It was indeed Adishankara of Advaita Sampradaya who made Bhagavad Gita popular by writing commentary on it. [Abhinavagupta of Kashmir Shaiva](https://archive.org/stream/ShrimatBhagavatGitaWithGitarthaSangrahaOfAbhinavaguptaIIDr.S.SankaraNarayanan/Shrimat%20Bhagavat%20Gita%20with%20Gitartha%20Sangraha%20of%20Abhinavagupta%20II%20-%20Dr.%20S.%20Sankara%20Narayanan#page/n155/mode/2up) (Trika) also wrote commentary of Bhagavadgita.

Krishna says following in Anugita when Arjuna asked Him to repeat Gita.

> 'Vasudeva said, 'I made thee listen to truths that are regarded as
>   mysteries. I imparted to thee truths that are eternal. Verily, I
>   discoursed to thee on Religion in its true form and on all the eternal
>   regions. It is exceedingly disagreeable to me to learn that thou didst
>   not, from folly, receive what I imparted. The recollection of all that
>   I told thee on that occasion will not come to me now. Without doubt, O
>   son of Pandu, thou art destitute of faith and thy understanding is not
>   good. It is impossible for me, O Dhananjaya, to repeat, in detail, all
>   that I said on that occasion. **That Dharma (about which I discoursed
>   to thee then) is more than sufficient for understanding Brahman. I
>   cannot discourse on it again in detail. I discoursed to thee on
>   Supreme Brahman, having concentrated myself in Yoga.** I shalt now,
>   however, recite to thee an old history upon the same topic. O foremost
>   of all persons, observant of duty, listen to everything I now say, so
>   that, with an understanding adapted to my teaching, thou mayst succeed
>   in attaining to the highest end. O chastiser of foes, on one occasion,
>   a Brahmana came to us from the regions of Heaven. Of irresistible
>   energy, he came from the regions of the Grandsire. He was duly
>   reverenced by us. Listen. O son of Pritha, without yielding to
>   scruples of any kind, to what he, O chief of Bharata's race, said, in
>   answer to our enquiries, agreeably to heavenly forms.'

Adishankara of Advaita Sampradaya says "Vasudeva" in verse 7.19 means "innermost self" or "pratyagatman". This is what [Adi Shankara says](https://archive.org/stream/Bhagavad-Gita.with.the.Commentary.of.Sri.Shankaracharya#page/n231/mode/2up) (translated by Alladi Mahadeva Sastri)

> 19. At the end of many births, the man Of  wisdom comes to me, (realising) that Vasudeva is the all : he is the noble-souled
>       (Mahatman), very  hard to find.
>
> **Commentary**: At the end of many births occupied in spiritual
>   regeneration as preparatory to the attainment of wisdom, the man of
>   mature wisdom resorts to **Me, Vasudeva. the innermost Self** 
>   (Pratyagatman) —Realising that Vasudeva is the All.  He who thus comes
>   to **Me, Narayana, the Self of All**, is a  Mahatman, a man of high
>   soul ; there is no other either equal  to him or superior to him.
>   Therefore such aman is very  hard to find ; it has indeed been said
>   that s' among thousands  of men, one perchance strives for perfection
>   " (vii. 3.)

Advaita Sampradaya emphasize on realizing our inner self (Atman) as ultimate reality.

Comment: @AnubhavJha, The Destroyer is Right in my question I already asked that what other sects believe in that particular sloka so he put his point on that, if you have your point you are free to give an answer.

Comment: Well, sorry if my comment was hurtful. Edit- I should delete my comment I guess.

Comment: @AnubhavJha, I understood your point that you are not agree with advaita points on that particular sloka. Same way they can also say that they are not agree with dvaita and visisthadvaita points. so this discussion will never end same as like discussion on who is supreme lord, here my post is not hurt or disrespect other sects or acharyas. I just want to know everyone opinions from believer of different sects, so we can understand each other beliefs and way of understanding about supreme lord. you can also states your answer regarding this thread.

Comment: Its not easy to understand the concept of Vasudev. From my limited intellect, what I could understand is According to Abhinavgupta, VAsudev is a state to be attained... And that state has manifestation who is called Vishnu.

Comment: @Rajas. You can add a separate answer from KS point of view.